# git svn clone stuck on perl.exe

Tags: windows, git, perl, svn, git-svn

I have executed command (Windows 10, Git BASH):

```
$ git svn clone <svn app-url>/trunk
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/TEMP/svn-git/trunk/.git/
```

and after it got stuck. No further logs, nothing.

The only thing i can see is that perl.exe is using loads of resources:

[image: perl.exe using lots of processor]

I have tried the same command on other windows PC in same network and it worked fine - started to get all revisions from r100 etc and finished in about an hour without problems.

Should I just be patient with this one?

Comment: I recently got the same issue on my Windows machine. Even with very small repositories, the process would not get past the "Initialized empty Git repository" line (I let a run for hours overnight). Finally I resorted to do all conversions in a Linux VM, where it worked like a charm.

Comment: What does `git --version` say on the working machine and the not working machine?

Comment: Version on working machine is `2.18.0.windows.1` while on NOT working is `2.20.1.windows.1` (so newer...). I will install 2.18 on not working machine and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [A.H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947357/a-h) I have installed version `2.18.0` and it worked!

It seems that there is some issue with the `2.20.1` version of Git for Windows which gets stuck on perl.exe. It seems to be connected with [this ticket in github](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1993) - I have tested `2.20.0` and it also works fine so the problem is only with the latest Git version.

Comment: I too have the problem with `2.20.1` on Windows.

Comment: Had similiar problems with 2.25, got a [portable](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.21.0.windows.1) 2.21 and suddenly it worked. It looks like they broke it again at one point ...